# Span not showing after click event fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with some data, and some cells are meant to be editable, those cells (td tags) contain a div and inside this div two elements: a span with an initial value and an empty input tag. If the user wants to edit a cell, span is hidden and input box shows up with span's text as its value.

But when the user leaves the input empty I can't make the span or the input to show up again.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//I get all the divs with a specific class name

    var editdivs = document.getElementsByClassName("divedit");

//And then attach an even listener

    for (var i = 0; i < editdivs.length; i++){
            editdivs[i].addEventListener("click", null);
    }

//I do the same for td tags

    var editspaces = document.getElementsByClassName("tabletoedit");
        for (var i = 0; i < editspaces.length; i++){
            editspaces[i].addEventListener("click", null);
        }

//show input to edit cell

    $(".divedit span").on("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.hide().siblings("input").val($this.text()).show();
        });


//And hide input, show span back

    $(".divedit input").on("blur", function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var value = determineValue( $this.val()); //some logic
            $this.hide().siblings("span").text(value).show();
        }).hide();

//This code works, console.log function logs the message, but span nor input //shows up if input is left empty:

    $(".tabletoedit").on("click", function () {
            console.log('inside td');
            var $this = $(this);
            //$this.hide().siblings("input").val($this.text()).show();
            $this.children("span").text("hello").show();
        });
```

What am I missing?
The thing is that having empty value is valid in this scenario.

**UPDATE**: Here the html portion, the original is huge, but this is the relevant part.

```
<tr>

<td rowspan="1" class="tabletoedit"><div id="key0-39" class="divedit"><span style="display: block;"></span><input style="display: none; background-color: rgb(102, 225, 115);"></div></td>
<td rowspan="1"><div id="key1-39"></div></td>
<td rowspan="1"><div id="key2-39"></div></td>
<td rowspan="1">test hgfhgf</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="text-align:right;">0</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="text-align:right;">0</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="text-align:right;">0</td>
<td rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="text-align:right;">0</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML

Comment: Instead of posting your code in pieces. Please insert it, as a whole, in your question including the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: var editpaces should be var editspaces

Comment: updated editpaces to editspaces

Comment: but this is not the problem, must have been a typo when copy and paste

Comment: can you please comment on why the down vote

Comment: You might want to add a function to set the span value back to it's initial value if the user leaves the input empty or prevent the user from doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just needed to get the input value using $this.val();

UPDATE - with the empty cell spans, make sure they have a width and height set in CSS or there won't be an element to click, then check to see if the span has text.

```js
   $(document).mouseup(function (e){
     // mouseclick on anywhere but the table
        $("input").hide();
      $(".divedit span").show();       
    });
       
    $(".divedit span").each (function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(e){                   
            $text = $(this).text();
            //check if the span is empty    
            if (!$text) {
                  $(this).parent().find("input").val('').show();
            } else {
                $(this).parent().find("input").val($text).show();
            } 
            // triggered a focus on the input so you don't need a double click
            $(this).parent().find("input").trigger( "focus" );
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });

    $(".divedit input").each (function(){
        $(this).on("change", function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings("span").text(value).show();
        });
    });
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.divedit span {
   height: 20px;
   width: 100px;
}
.divedit input {
   height: 20px;
   width: 100px;
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="1" class="tabletoedit">
  <div id="key0-39" class="divedit">
    <span style="display: block;"></span>
    <input style=" background-color: rgb(102, 225, 115);">
  </div>
</td>
<td rowspan="1" class="tabletoedit">
  <div id="key0-39" class="divedit">
    <span style="display: block;">test</span>
    <input style=" background-color: rgb(102, 225, 115);">
  </div>
</td>
<td rowspan="1" class="tabletoedit">
  <div id="key0-39" class="divedit">
    <span style="display: block;">test</span>
    <input style=" background-color: rgb(102, 225, 115);">
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your code doesn't change the div to span when the focus has moved

Comment: Yeah, seems good. I could also learn the skills from your code, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I've changed your code a bit, but the logic you would need is quite similar. So, don't be obsessed with HTML part, just focus on the logic and the idea.

Plain JavaScript:

```js
var body = document.getElementById('body');
var span = document.getElementById('span');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target != span && e.target!= input){
    span.textContent = input.value;
    span.style.visibility = 'visible';
    input.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
})

span.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  input.value = this.textContent;
  input.style.visibility = 'visible';
});
```

```css
body{
  width:300px;
  height:250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body id='body'>
  <span id='span'>Name</span>
  <input id='input' type='text' value='Name'/>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
var body = $('#body');
var span = $('#span');
var input = $('#input');

body.on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target != span[0] && e.target!= input[0]){
    span.text(input.val());
    span.css('visibility', 'visible');
    input.css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
});

span.on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  input.val(span.text());
  input.css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: your script has the same problem mine does. Once span is empty wont show up again